# Angular2 - unable to retrieve data from API

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, angular

I am currently building an Angular2 application accessing an MVC web API i have built. However, it does not seem to retrieve any data. I am obviously missing something but i am not sure what.

I know that the URL i am using works along with the headers as i am able to retrieve the data correctly through fiddler.

My repack.service.ts is as follows:

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { RepackIndex } from './RepackIndex';

@Injectable()
export class RepackService{
    private baseUrl = 'https://localhost:44321/api/Repack/All';

    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getAllRepacks(): Promise<RepackIndex[]>{
        var data =  this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
                         .toPromise()
                         .then(response => response.json().data as RepackIndex[])
                          .catch(this.handleError);

        return data;
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any>{
        console.error("An error occured in repack.service", error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

And this is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';

import { RepackIndex }       from './repackIndex'; 
import { RepackService }     from './repack.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'index',
    templateUrl: 'app/index.component.html',
    providers: [RepackService]
})

export class IndexComponent implements OnInit{
    repacks: RepackIndex[];
    selectedRepack: RepackIndex;

    constructor(private router: Router, private repackService: RepackService) { }

    onSelect(repack: RepackIndex): void{
        this.selectedRepack = repack;
    }

    getRepacks(): void{
        this.repackService.getAllRepacks().then(repacks => this.repacks =     repacks);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void{
         this.getRepacks();
    }
}
```

I have tried putting in a breakpoint and adding a console.log line but no data is returned to the component.

I am fairly new to Angular2 so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure `https://localhost:44321/api/Repack/All` returns correct result?

Comment: Yes like i said i have tried the exact url (copy and paste) in fiddler and it returns successfully

Comment: Sorry, missed that part :)

Comment: No worries easily done :)

Comment: No errors? Please check if the http request is started (dev-tools) .. please check if there's any response (dev-tools) and put in a console.log into the `.then()` inside of your service..

Comment: @mxii - i have put a breakpoint in the app so i can confirm that it is reaching the api and the api retrieves the data successfully. how do i put a console.log in the `.then()` along with the other code? could you provide an example please

Comment: @mxii - also looking at it in the console, the data is retrieved correctly so it appears to be how im handling the data on its return

Comment: try: `this.repackService.getAllRepacks().then(response => this.repacks = response.json().data as RepackIndex[]);`. If it works I'll explain

Comment: No it doesnt like that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I have managed to get it to work by using an observable rather than a promise.

My service method now looks like this:

```typescript
public GetAll = (): Observable<RepackIndex[]> => {
      return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
                    .map((response: Response) => <RepackIndex[]>response.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And my Component call now looks like this:

```typescript
getRepacks(): void{
        this.repackService.GetAll()
                            .subscribe((data:RepackIndex[]) => this.repacks = data,
                            error => console.log(error),
                            () => console.log('Get All repacks complete'));
}
```

I found the answer  [here](http://offering.solutions/articles/angular/consuming-a-rest-api-with-angular-2-http-service-in-typescript/)

Hope this helps someone else